# Problema String Linguagem C

Tags: c

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não consigo entende por que o programa não executa a verificação.
Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Não coloque print do codigo, cole aqui na pergunta. Dê uma olhada no nosso [código de conduta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/conduct)

Comment: @FábioMorais O código de conduta tem orientações gerais sobre como se comportar no site, mas não explica como melhorar as perguntas. Para entender especificamente porque é ruim colocar imagens do código em vez do próprio código em texto, eu sugiro o [**Manual de como não fazer perguntas**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/112052) <-- **Jean, sugiro que leia** e entenda porque imagens com código não são a forma ideal de se perguntar. Leia também o **[tour]** e a página **[ask]**, e veja também como montar um **[mcve]**. Depois você pode voltar aqui e **[edit]** a pergunta